# How to scrape Instacart delivery times for different locations with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

So, I wanted to build a scraper which would be able to scrape instacart for their delivery times, but for DIFFERENT locations. I am not sure how to do it. I have tried using `https://www.instacart.com/v3/containers/NAME_OF_STORE/next_gen/retailer_information/content/delivery?source=web`, but it only lets me scrape the data for my location inputted from my account. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks. 
BTW: I tried api.instacart.com, but it looks like it is just instacart.com with a different url. If I am wrong, please guide me in the right direction. I feel extremely lost right now, trying to come up with a way to scrape(or use an API) data from their website right now. Thanks.